# Laravel submit doesn't work when form is in different containers

Tags: forms, laravel-5

I'm working on a Laravel 5.3 project and I'm in the process of deploying to a staging server. For staging I used latest Laravel(5.4). Now, one of the problems is that locally, a form which is spread on some table cells is working, but on the staging version the submit button doesn't do anything (like it not part of the form).

```
<tbody>
    {!! Form::model($job = new \App\Models\Job, ['url' => 'admin/job']) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('person', $person->id) !!}
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" class="form-group">
              {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
          </td>
          <td class="form-group">
              {!! Form::submit('Adauga', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
          </td>
        </tr>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
        @foreach($jobs as $job)
             <tr> ....
```

On inspector both version are displaying the form opening and closing on the same line, but the local variant does send the request.

html in inspector:
[image]

Does dividing a form's inputs in different containers is sloppy?

Comment: Inspector shows the dom - the browsers attempt to fix your awful html. Instead view source, thats the actual html output - make sure that is valid. Probably the browser has successfully fixed your error on the local machine, but the staging server is outputting slightly more broken html. Both environments should be equal if you want to avoid huge headaches, but ultimately you need to fix the html

Comment: Read the MDN docs for `tbody` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody. The permitted content is zero or more `tr` elements. A `form` is not permitted, hence the browser isn't interpreting your HTML as you might expect. Refactor your code to make the HTML valid.